# Como remover borda dos input e textarea de todos os browsers, quando clicado?

Tags: html, css

Olhem só a imagem para ter uma idéia:

[image: textarea]

Quando clicado essa borda com shadow azul fica visível. Acho que é padrão de todos os browser.

Alguma solução?

Comment: Talvez você queira colocar mais detalhes como o fato de estar usando o Bootstrap.

A sua pergunta parecia um pouco mais geral, mas agora parece ter um contexto específico (tem a ver com um framework específico).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Isso não é padrão de todos os browser, isso eu posso te garantir.

Se isso está acontecendo em todos os browsers, existe a possibilidade de você está usando [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) ou alguma outra biblioteca que tenha [css](/questions/tagged/css) embutido

Caso sim manipule esse **css** para deixar da forma que lhe agrada

```
textarea:focus, input:focus, select:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
    border: 0 none;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Este é um exemplo de css que removeria tanto as bordas quanto o efeito de sobra em azul

Comment: Nossa, acabei de ver que era o bootstrap que estava fazendo isso. Obrigado ai @ErlonCharles

Comment: Se quiser pode marcar a resposta como correta eu agradeço hehe
:D

Comment: kkkkk, esqueci @ErlonCharles. Ja esta como correta agora!

Comment: Adicionado ao meu reset.css pessoal! Obrigado!

Comment: perfeito, procurei demais!!

Answer (score 4):

A borda é usada para mostrar que um elemento está em foco (quando você digita algo ou aperta o botão enter).

Você pode removê-la assim:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus, select:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

É bom lembrar que com essa mesma regra você também pode personalizar esse comportamento (ao invés de simplesmente removê-lo).

Isso, inclusive, é aconselhável, uma vez que por questões de usabilidade é preferível que o usuário tenha sempre uma maneira de saber qual elemento tem o foco atualmente.

Resposta adaptada deste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome).

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o atributo `outline` do CSS, como no exemplo:

```css
input, textarea, select {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Veja o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7ab8/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você esteja usando *ASP.NET MVC 5* que utiliza *Twitter Bootstrap*, então você poderia adicionar esse CSS no seu arquivo Site.css

```
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #cccccc;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir uma classe ou id para o componente, por exemplo:

```html
<input class="form-itens">
```

E depois configurar no arquivo CSS:

```css
.form-itens:focus {
   box-shadow:none;
}
```

Isso irá resolver.

Answer (score -3):

Bom hj em dia só o

```
input
{
  outline: 0;
}
```

ja resolve